# How optimze complex query django 1.8

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset

I have a query taking about 36 seconds to run, this is unviable, I've tried using select_related and prefetch, but the results don't improve.

This my query:

```
job_list = Job.objects.filter(Q(hiring_manager=emp) | Q(
                        followers=emp)).values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

emp is:

```
emp = Employee.objects.filter(
                        user=self.request.user, firm=obj).first().pk
```

Then i use in:

```
_candidates = Candidate.objects.filter(
                        job__in=job_list,
                        apply_date__range=[date_initial, date_end]
                    ).order_by('-apply_date')
```

And ater:

`_candidates.count()`

This SQL:

```
SQL Executed:
SELECT ...
FROM `combo_candidate` WHERE (
    `combo_candidate`.`job_id` IN (
        SELECT ... FROM `combo_job` U0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `combo_job_followers` U2 ON U0.`id` = U2.`job_id`
        WHERE U0.`hiring_manager_id` = 9482 OR U2.`user_id` = 9482
          AND `combo_candidate`.`apply_date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01 02:00:00' AND '2019-02-01 02:00:00'
    )
Time
33402,8768539 ms
```

**hiring_manager is a FK in Job, followers is m2m in model Job**

Comment: This is not the query for *this* queryset, you use `job_list` in another `QuerySet`.

Comment: i use in ```_candidates = Candidate.objects.filter(
                        job__in=job_list,
                        apply_date__range=[date_initial, date_end]
                    ).order_by('-apply_date')``` and later _candidates.count()

Comment: @GustavoNugueira: it might make more sense to here run the subquery in a separate one, like `Candidate.objects.filter(job__in=list(job_list), apply_date__range=...)`.

Comment: Wow this optimize for about 2 seconds, could you explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason that this takes so long is because the database runs the subquery for each element in your `combo_candidate` table, and thus if the number of candidates is high, then it will make a lot of subqueries.

The subquery is however "static": it does not require to be evaluated multiple times, since nothing in the subquery refers to the world "outside" the query. We thus can make two queries here: one where evaluate the subquery, and one where we evaluate the outer query.

We can force evaluation, for example by using `list(..)`:

```
_candidates = Candidate.objects.filter(
    job__in=list(job_list),
    apply_date__range=[date_initial, date_end]
).order_by('-apply_date')
```

Answer (score 2):

Excellent suggestion by @WillemVanOnsem. I am just attaching the Django documentation.

As per the Django documentation

> Performance considerations
>
> Be cautious about using nested queries and understand your database
>   server’s performance characteristics (if in doubt, benchmark!). Some
>   database backends, most notably MySQL, don’t optimize nested queries
>   very well. It is more efficient, in those cases, to extract a list of
>   values and then pass that into the second query. That is, execute two
>   queries instead of one:
>
> ```py
> values = Blog.objects.filter(
>         name__contains='Cheddar').values_list('pk', flat=True)
>
> entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=list(values))
> ```
>
> Note the list() call around the Blog QuerySet to force execution of
>   the first query. Without it, a nested query would be executed, because
>   QuerySets are lazy.

I place special emphasis on the **"Note the list() call around the Blog QuerySet to force execution of the first query. Without it, a nested query would be executed, because QuerySets are lazy."**

Hope it helps